# Возможно ли навредить БД через AutoCompleteTextView?

Tags: java, android, база-данных, взлом

У меня есть `AutoCompleteTextView`, данные с которой попадают в переменную, затем на сервере непосредственно в БД SQlite, возможно ли через неё как-то навредить БД? Если да, то как защититься?

БД *SQlite*
работаю через `Socket`

Comment: какая БД? Как делаются запросы?

Comment: @metalurgus подредактировал

Comment: Если вы конкатенируете строки вручную в SQL-запрос, то что угодно может навредить БД.

Comment: да, можно навредить. ПРи помощи SQL- инъекций, например. Защититься можно при помощи prepared-запроссов

Comment: А правильно было бы не соединяться через Socket, а использоввать API

Comment: @metalurgus а есть ли способ в AutoCompleteTextView ограничить в вод определённых символов ?

Comment: есть, после каждого символа проверять, разрешенный ли он. Но это опять же костыльный подход.

Comment: @metalurgus хорошо, а возможно где то в properties или в activity_main.xml их указать ?

Comment: @metalurgus пожалуйста распишите свой ответ про SQL- инъекции подробней  так как не совсем понятно как это возможно сделать у меня данные из переменной сразу же помещаться через запрос к БД в у заказанный столбик в таблице и они не где не участвуют в коде если и будет что то написано в AutoCompleteTextView то оно сразу же попадёт в таблицу и будет храниться там ?

Comment: Покажите свой код, тогда я смогу что-нибудь ответить подробнее

Comment: @metalurgus в общем я придумал проще распарсиваю данные при приёме на сервере из спец знаков оставляю только точки и запятые так же исключаю латиницу, вся кириллица поступает в бд.

Comment: Каком приеме на сервере? У вас же соединение прямо с базой, без сервера. Вы же говорили так. Кроме того, это абсолютно не проще

Comment: @metalurgus "попадают в переменную, затем на сервере непосредственно в БД SQlite"        а почему не проще теперь любой скрипт исключен ?

Comment: а-а, в оригинале было "данные с которой попадают не посредственно в БД SQlite". Я не обратил внимания на обновления. Но тем не менее - так, как вы сделали - не проше. На сервере достаточно было реализовать prepared statement Запрос